# For workspace.getConfiguration: how do I get a setting from the Multi Root Workspace file (.code-workspace)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

With [`WorkspaceConfiguration.update(...)`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration.update) you can specify that the setting needs to be written to the `ConfigurationTarget.Workspace`. This updates the Workspace `.code-workspace` file if Multi Root or it updates the WorkspaceFolder `.vscode/settings.json` if opened a single folder.

Now I want to get the current setting from the Workspace (`.code-workspace` or `.vscode/settings.json`).

What is the [`ConfigurationScope`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ConfigurationScope) I need to set in the call to [`workspace.getConfiguration`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace.getConfiguration)?

What is the URI I need to use? The `TextDocument` and `WorkspaceFolder` will always get me the value from `.vscode/settings.json`

Answer (score 5):

I found the method [`WorkspaceConfiguration.inspect`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration.inspect). It shows the unmerged parts of the setting.

In my extension I have setup a `configuration` setting with `"scope": "resource"`

```json
      "configuration": {
        "title": "Test Config",
        "properties": {
          "extension.someconfig": {
            "type": "string",
            "scope": "resource",
            "description": "some test configuration setting",
            "default": "default-value"
          }
        }
      }
```

Defined a value for the Global/User level: `"extension.someconfig": "user-value"`

Setup a command to log a few things depending on the current file. I don't log the language parts of `inspect` because I don't use them (and where do you define them).

```javascript
    let uri = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri;
    let config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('extension', uri);
    console.log('---------');
    console.log('someconfig:', config.get('someconfig'));
    let inspect = config.inspect('someconfig');
    console.log('inspect.key:', inspect.key);
    console.log('inspect.defaultValue:', inspect.defaultValue);
    console.log('inspect.globalValue:', inspect.globalValue);
    console.log('inspect.workspaceValue:', inspect.workspaceValue);
    console.log('inspect.workspaceFolderValue:', inspect.workspaceFolderValue);
```

I have setup a test MR Workspace:

```
testconfig
  + project1
  |   + .vscode
  |   |   + settings.json    // "extension.someconfig": "project1-value"
  |   + main.py
  + project2
  |   + .vscode
  |   |   + settings.json    // "extension.someconfig": "project2-value"
  |   + main.py
  + project3
  |   + .vscode
  |   |   + settings.json    // "extension.someconfig": "project3-value"
  |   + main.py
  + testconfig.code-workspace      // "extension.someconfig": "workspace-value"
```

When I log the setting for a **non-scoped** `getConfiguration`:

```
let config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('extension');
```

```
All 3 main.py files give:

someconfig: workspace-value
inspect.key: extension.someconfig
inspect.defaultValue: default-value
inspect.globalValue: user-value
inspect.workspaceValue: workspace-value
inspect.workspaceFolderValue: undefined
```

When using the **scoped** `getConfiguration`:

```
let config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('extension', uri);
```

```
Common for all 3 main.py files:
inspect.key: extension.someconfig
inspect.defaultValue: default-value
inspect.globalValue: user-value
inspect.workspaceValue: workspace-value

--------- project1/main.py:
someconfig: project1-value
inspect.workspaceFolderValue: project1-value
--------- project2/main.py:
someconfig: project2-value
inspect.workspaceFolderValue: project2-value
--------- project3/main.py:
someconfig: project3-value
inspect.workspaceFolderValue: project3-value
```

When scoped to the WorkspaceFolder

```javascript
let uri = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri;
let workspaceFolder = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(uri);
let config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('extension', workspaceFolder);
```

The results are the same as for file scoped.

---

When the merged setting is determined the `workspaceFolderValue` is `undefined` for the non-scoped `getConfiguration` call.

The `inspect` call uses the same scope as the `getConfiguration` call that returned the `WorkspaceConfiguration`

Comment: Sigh, how many times have I looked at the `WorkspaceConfiguration` documentation and not *seen* that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain my limited understanding of what is going on here (as a relative rookie to extension coding).

Say I have these two commands:

```js
const codeWorkspaceConfigs = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('launch'); // no scope argument

const launchConfigs = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('launch', workSpace.uri);
```

with no scope argument I get the `launch` settings from that `*.code-workspace` file only.  Even if the `<someName>.code-workspace` file is in some weird unrelated place from the project's code.  So that I believe is the short answer to your question.  But it is more interesting.

Say I do have a 'launch.json '  file in a workspaceFolder, then on calling the second workspaced-scope `getConfiguration()` I get *only* that workspaceFolder's `launch.json` settings.  Whether there is a `code-workspace` with `launch` settings or not.

But if there is a `.code-workspace`  but *no* workspaceFolder `launch.json` then the second workspaced-scoped call gets me the `.code-workspace` settings!

As it should, since now there are no local settings anymore to override the more global `.code-workspace` settings.

Initially I misunderstand that `ConfigurationScope` parameter.

`ConfigurationScope: Uri | TextDocument | WorkspaceFolder | {languageId: string, uri: Uri}`

I thought that the `WorkspaceFolder`  would get the settings actually listed in that WorksapceFolder's `.vscode/settings.json` but then why would there be a `TextDocument` or `Uri` option (where there wouldn't necessarily be any settings.  But you are limiting the scope to those settings that apply to that document or uri - and that is the result of local settings overriding global settings, for example.

`const codeWorkspaceConfigs = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('launch'); // no scope argument`

for me with this non-scoped version I get the `.code-workspace` settings only.  While `ConfigurationScope` is an optional parameter to the `getConfiguration()` command I don't see any place that tells you what will happen (what the scope might be) if it is omitted.  Maybe that is obvious to others, but it isn't to me.

To get a specific setting from `.code-workspace` this works for me:

```js
let settings = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().get('commandAlias.category');
```

and that setting is in both `.code-workspace` and in user `settings.json`.  And it doesn't seem to matter what file is active at the time the configuration is retrieved.

[image: getting code-workspace settings]

Comment: In the doc about `WorkspaceConfiguration` they mention that `launch` is the section  string, like `editor.wordWrap`, to use if you want to get the content of `launch.json`. The same for `tasks` as section name. My question is about any setting, like `editor.wordWrap` or `myextname.regex-foo`. `getConfiguration` will always give you the merged/override on all levels. For an `Open Folder` it is known which `WorkspaceFolder` to use (there is no `Workspace` level). For MR Workspace (`.code-workspace`) you need the `scope` parameter to tell which `WorkspaceFolder` to use.

Comment: I don't know which `WorkspaceFolder` is used if there is no scope mentioned in a MR Workspace case. Do they use the `WorkspaceFolder` of the current active file, but what if there is no file open ----- I don't talk about the language scoped settings (to me that is still a mystery, I don't do language related stuff yet)

Comment: I used `launch` because I had it handy, but I get unmerged `.code-workspace` settings only if I use `let settings = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().get('commandAlias.category');` to get a that setting which is in both `.code-workspace` and in user `settings.json`. I added that to the answer. So if you try `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().get('someSetting)` you get the merged result?

Comment: Have you marked `commandAlias.category` as a setting with `"scope": "resource"` in `package.json`, the default scope is `window` and a setting in the workspaceFolder is not relevant then, I assume. `getConfiguration` without scope is a mystery which workspaceFolder will be used in the merged result

Comment: I found another method that helps with the config parts