# vscode extension read global configuration

Tags: vscode-extensions

`vscode.workspace.getConfiguration()` return workspace configuration

is there any way to read the global configuration?

I tried `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('', vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0])` and it does not work

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65256908.